# Which of the ridiculous vehicles in The Lego Batman Movie have appeared in other Batman canon?

Tags: dc, batman, the-lego-batman-movie

There's a whole bunch of ridiculous vehicles in *The Lego Batman Movie*. Among them is The Bat-shuttle, Robin's Jetski, the Bat-Sub, and the Bat-Kayak. (I cannot find a full list online. Not all the rididculous vehicles in the movie have been made into official Lego sets.)

Have any of these vehicles appeared in other Batman canon?

Comment: https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Bat-Sub

Comment: Bat Space Rocket; http://i289.photobucket.com/albums/ll223/darknight2k/bat%20pics%202/batspaceship1.jpg

Comment: https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Vehicle_Galleries

Comment: Ridiculous _until_ you need to go to space / to Miami / underwater / white-water rafting. Everyone loooooves how prepared Batman is until they see the kayak.

Comment: By 'ridiculous' I think you mean 'awesome'.

Comment: I'm pretty sure all of them.

Comment: @Valorum that is obvious.

Comment: Batman Movie Concept Art vehicles: http://conceptartworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/The-LEGO-Batman-Movie-The-Making-of-the-Movie-Concept-Art-174-175.jpg